# Merge firefox-related tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, firefox

Now that Mozilla is rolling out Firefox releases so quickly, does it really pay to keep creating separate tags for each new version?  We currently have tags for firefox 3-6 including several incremental tags of three.

Wouldn't it be neater to tag all questions on [firefox-5](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/firefox-5) and later under the generic [firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/firefox)?  They should be synonyms at the very least.

Comment: I think this is a good idea. +1 from me.

Comment: I agree. With Firefox's major version numbers increasing this quickly and with fewer changes than before, they lose all useful meaning as a means of separating between questions related to specific releases and the major product changes these releases brought.

Comment: Should we also be adding [tag:firefox-4] and 3, etc?

Answer (score 7):

<s>I'm still debating whether the synonym should exist at all - we have [firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/firefox) as the generic tag for *all* Firefox versions, while the version-specific tags can still remain & be applied for questions having problems with specific versions.</s>

Also, going forward Firefox more or less has decided to dump the version tag - so till people embrace the no-version-Firefox much like they have embraced Chrome, I don't think the synonym mapping would be required.

This is done

- https://meta.superuser.com/a/4538/4377
- https://meta.superuser.com/a/4537/4377

Answer (score 2):

Unless its something specific to an older version, or UI related (since ff4+ does have a significantly different UI). 
On the short run, it makes sense to me to merge all of 3x family tags up - since its going to be updated and some people will be stick with it support ends, or their distro upgrades and keep everything else together, and apply the generic firefox tag for anything at all.

I'd also note FF has considered dropping user-facing version numbers - which would decide this for us.

Comment: got some typos - read your first line... :)

Comment: fixed. misteaks happen :)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. For now I suggest *not* having Firefox-4, Firefox-5, Firefox-6 version tags and just keep them all as perhaps.. something that indicates "new firefox"?

Can we make the generic [firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/firefox) tag work in this case for now, until Mozilla decides if they're going fully Chrome-infinite-version?