# Should we merge tags `sublime-text`, `sublime-text-2` and `sublime-text-3`?

Tags: discussion, tags

Whenever I ask a question regarding sublime text, I always include all three of these tags in order to attract the attention of anyone who has any one of them subscribed. This is because the programs are so similar that it is very often not important what version you are using. And I could easily see people writing "In ST3, you can use..." for questions tagged ST2 because that is a useful answer; if not to the person asking, then to future readers.

I agree that I'm likely using the tags incorrectly this way, but it also feel wrong to not include one of them because it's an easy way to get desired, useful attention.  Are the three different tags truly necessary? We don't have tons of version tags for other programs; see [Firefox versions going to infinity – should we merge the tags?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4532/firefox-versions-going-to-infinity-should-we-merge-the-tags)

Comment: In the tag wiki summary for [sublime-text]: Use this tag for version-agnostic questions.  How many users would subscribe to only [sublime-text-2] or [sublime-text-3]?

Comment: @fixer1234 probably not many. I am subscribed to all three, and it's super annoying to have to click all three of them to check for any new ST questions.